# Creation of a class instance by reflection in Python does not work

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
theModule = locate(<the location of my python script in the file system>)
class_ = getattr(theModule, '<the class of my module>')
myAppli = class_()
```

But I always have an AttributeError exception when trying to perform the "getattr" method.

My objective was to create a Python class from a file somewhere in the file system, and execute methods on it by reflection without using the class declaration in the Python code.

### Example

For example, I have the following python script, let's say that the name of the script file is: myScript.py

```
import sys

class PythonAppli:
  def aMethod(self):
    sys.echo('I am here\n')
```

And I perform this in another script in the same directory:

```
from pydoc import locate

theModule = locate('myScript.py')
class_ = getattr(theModule, 'pythonAppli')
myAppli = class_()
```

I have the following exception on the "getattr" line:

```
AttributeError: class PythonAppli has no attribute 'pythonAppli'
```

Note that if I add this line before my "getattr" method call:

```
inspect.getmembers(theModule)
```

I find 'pythonAppli' in the list of attributes.

I looked on the question about dynamic instanciation on StackOverflow but could not find my error here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some actual code we can help debug. So far we have no way of knowing whether the problem is in your code, in your input or in your module/class. See [ask] on how to provide a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: Note that the error message implies that ``theModule`` already is your desired class, not the module containing said class.

Comment: I edited my example. Is it clearer?

Comment: Ah your are right, about your last remark. Can I answer to my own question after you closed it? It could be useful to others.

Comment: If you [edit] your answer first so that it is on-topic, it can be nominated for re-opening. As it currently stands, it is unclear from the question itself what the problem actually is, preventing anyone else with the same problem from knowing whether an answer applies to them as well.

Comment: "Is it clearer?" I'm afraid not. It is still entirely unclear what ``locate`` and its inputs are, and there is still no minimal, reproducible example. Three out of four code snippets are not executable at all, containing pseudo-code placeholders.

Comment: And with the updated code? Only the example part contains executable code. The beginning is just to explain the problem.

Comment: And BTW I can't post an answer because the topic is closed (I can only edit the question, which is what I did twice to address your remarks). Your small comment made me understand why it was not working, but I can't explain it for others now that I understood it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per MisterMiyagi answer, my mistake was `theModule` was already my desired class. The following code did work:

```
from pydoc import locate

theModule = locate('myScript.py')
pythonAppli = theModule()
```

So it was much more simple that I imagined.